# How to define size of input in Recurrent Neural Network for unsupervised learning model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to fit a neural network model(unsupervised).
I have only an input x, which is a vector with 10000 components, and I have an output, which is also a vector of the same size as x.
I've created the model using the below mentioned code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20,input_shape= (10000,1),activation='tanh',return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='tanh'))
```

I'm here confused about the input shape, as I'm getting a warning message which reads:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 10000, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 10000, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='simple_rnn_2_input'), name='simple_rnn_2_input', description="created by layer 'simple_rnn_2_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (10000, 1, 1).
```

How should I define the input shape within the model and the input shape used for calling the model, so as to match which that of the model?

Also, is it possible to call the same model using different input sizes, like vector with `10000/100/50` components?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what is MLP and basics of it?

Comment: yes I have been reading and trying to understand, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to this question of yours,

> Also, is it possible to call the same model using different input
> sizes, like vector with 10000/100/50 components?

the answer is Yes. It doesn't matter what your inputs are so far your model layers have the correct shape mentioned as per the input. Check the syntax of SimpleRNN as mentioned in [tf.org-api-docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SimpleRNN).

`tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN` takes inputs as a **3D tensor, with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].**

Next, so far the shape error is concerned ,

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 10000, 1)
> .
> .
> 'simple_rnn_2_input'"), but it was called on an input with
> incompatible shape (10000, 1, 1).

As you have mentioned , your input and outputs look like this :

```
input_data.shape(),output_data.shape()
```

output :

```
(10000,1),(10000,1)
```

You need to modify the line 2 of your code mentioned as :

```
model = keras.models.Sequential() 
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 1,1)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(20,input_shape= (10000,1,1),activation='tanh',return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
```

Along with that, you also need to reshape your inputs as :

```
input_data = input_data.reshape(10000,1,1)
```